# how does the correlation of independent variables affect the correlation of parameters

Tags: regression, correlation, expected-value

Suppose $Y$,$X$ and $Z$ are correlated random variables with $N(0,1)$.

We have these cross-sectional regression for each time $t$

$Y_{t} = \beta_{t}X_{t}+u_{t} $

$Y_{t} = \theta_{t}Z_{t}+\epsilon_{t} $

We can extimate the cross sectional correlation (or covariance) of $X_{t}$ and $Z_{t}$ at each time $t$ as $corr(X_{t},Z_{t})$ lets say it is $c_{t}$.

I would like to work out how this correlation between $X_{t}$ and $Z_{t}$ affects the parameter estimates of $\beta_{t}$ and $\theta_{t}$. In particular I was hoping to get a formulaic expression on how $c_{t}$ affects the correlation between the time series of the parameter estimates of $\beta_{t}$ and $\theta_{t}$.

Please let ke know if this is still unclear.

Many thanks

Comment: "*Suppose $Y$,$X$ and $Z$ are correlated random variables with $N(0,1)$.*" ... do you mean they are trivariate normal with standard normal margins? Or is the joint distribution unknown? When you put the subscript $t$ on, is there time-dependence either within or across series?

Answer (score -1):

R code :

```
  library(MASS)
  simuCor<-function(corXZ){
  sigmaXZ <- matrix(c(1, corXZ, corXZ, 1), ncol=2)
  XZ = mvrnorm(n = 1000,mu = c(0, 0), sigmaXZ)
  X = XZ[,1]
  Z = XZ[,2]
  #We assume there is a relaitonship
  #You can try another parameter setting
  Y = 0.2*X + 0.7*Z  + rnorm(n = 1000, 0, 0.1)
  cYX = summary(lm(Y~X))$coefficients[2,1]
      cYZ = summary(lm(Y~Z))$coefficients[2,1]
  return(c(cYX, cYZ))
}

resultY=t(sapply(seq(0,1,by=0.01),simuCor))
apply(resultY,2,mean)
var(resultY)    


plot(seq(0,1,by=0.01),resultY[,1], xlab='Correlaltion of XZ',ylab='The OLS estimate of Beta')
plot(seq(0,1,by=0.01),resultY[,2], xlab='Correlaltion of XZ',ylab='The OLS estimate of Theta')
```

As the result shows,

"The more significant the correlation is, the more you will be away from the true value when respectively using OLS."

Actually the parameters model structure that generates Y will determine the explicit expression of your deduction. But the example here can give you an intuitive explanation.

Comment: Thanks for this - this makes sense. However, I was really hoping for some analytical result.